# issues with Twitter API

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I am using Twitter API with my application. I can login through my twitter account and can also get my followers list. Now I want to send them direct messages, I have tried some code but not get succeed.

```
function tweetf(screenname) {

  var params = 'tweetname='+screenname+'&tweetmsg=I just joined Aviesta and I love it! I think you will too! Gorgeous shoes chosen each month just for you.'; 

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json',
    data: { screen_name:screenname,text:'hello'},
    success: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }                        
  });
}
```

I am not getting any error in console but it does not work.

Is there any parameter I am missing which I have to send or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

According [API documention](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new) you need to use HTTP POST method.

Comment: i know and i tried that but same response as i get with GET. And I have used GET for testing purpose so that i can know screen name and text is attached to url or not.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new

> Requires both the user and text parameters and must be a **POST**

Comment: i know and i tried that but same response as i get with GET. And I have used GET for testing purpose so that i can know screen name and text is attached to url or not.